# -R uploading a folder with Spanish characters in file name returns an error

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, gsutil

I'm trying to upload a collection of folders with files (with different file extensions) to my bucket using gsutil. I'm using the following command:

```
gsutil -m cp -R -L dir gs://my_bucket
```

It uploads the documents fine until in encounters a file name ("Opinió ITAE3") that contains characters like `ó` and other Spanish characters, and gives me this error:

> [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified: u'C:\Users\anton\Desktop\Test\Test\Opinio\xb4 ITAE3.txt'
>   CommandException: 1 file/object could not be transferred.

Many of the files are pretty old. When I create a file with a name like `éóá.txt` it works fine. But it doesn't work for that old file. It looks like it has something to do with encoding.

What can I do to upload these documents along with others?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the Cloud Storage documentation for [Filename encoding and interoperability problems](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/addlhelp/Filenameencodingandinteroperabilityproblems):

> Users with files stored in other encodings (such as Latin 1) must convert those filenames to UTF-8 before attempting to upload the files.

And it suggests:

> If you have too many files for that to be practical you can use a tool to convert the old character encoding to UTF-8. One such tool is [native2ascii](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/native2ascii.html).